# ViewController animation like zooming and zooming out

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, zooming

I have a `CustomGridView` with `UIView` for images, if i click on an image It should be show in another viewcontroller with Zoomin Transition (It should show like it comes out from the grid), when i closing that it should animate like it goes back to the same place like Zoomout effect,

I searched for this i unable to find the library that suited my needs, can somebody suggest how can i achieve this

[image]

Comment: What about creating another view controller that accepts UIImage and Frame of the image with respect to the viewController's view. This new view controller will have clear background view, and will have imageview of same size as frame of image in previous VC, and will resize it to get full screen animatedly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are searching for JTSImageViewController

See:
https://github.com/jaredsinclair/JTSImageViewController

Comment: this solves my problem and i customized it for my needs thank you

Answer (score 3):

I have just created an example project for you.

https://github.com/khuong291/100DaysOfSwift (Project 53)

Hope this help.