# How can I Zoom in/out Animation when present UIViewController in Swift 4?

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiviewcontroller

I want to present `ViewController` from button Click with Zoom-In/Out Animation, I try some code but it won't worked for me:

```
func btnClickView(_ sender: UIButton) {
   let objImagePreview = ImagePreview(nibName: "ImagePreview", bundle: nil)
            let transition = CATransition()
            transition.duration = 1
            transition.type = kCATransitionMoveIn
            transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromTop
            transition.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)
            view.window!.layer.add(transition, forKey: kCATransition)
            self.present(objImagePreview, animated: false, completion: nil)
}
```

I want to animate `UIViewController` not `UIView` . I tried so many things but it won't worked for me.

Comment: The easy way: https://github.com/lkzhao/Hero

Comment: The Transition property belongs to UIView not UIViewController.When you want to animate UIViewController it means it will work from UIViewController.view

Comment: but when i present a uiviewcontroller it should be in Zoom-in Animation , i don't know how to do it but if you have code for Animation then please give me .

Comment: Are you aiming to display the zoom in/out transition from the middle of the view controller(s)?

Comment: @AhmadF yes i want this any solution for this?

Comment: @DixitAkabari are you using segues?

Comment: @AhmadF Nope  self.present(myVc, animated: true, completion: nil).

Comment: @DixitAkabari these could be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36956332/viewcontroller-animation-like-zooming-and-zooming-out https://medium.com/@masamichiueta/create-transition-and-interaction-like-ios-photos-app-2b9f16313d3 https://github.com/chbo297/CCZoomTransition

Comment: @AhmadF let me check. thank you.

Answer (score 6):

I hope this will be help,

in the first view controller set destination ViewController with `vc.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext` before present it, and set animated as false while present like this

```
if let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DestinationViewController") as? DestinationViewController {
            vc.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
            self.present(vc, animated: false, completion: nil)
        }
```

and then in the DestinationViewController when viewWillAppear create zoom animation like this

```
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        view.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.00001, y: 0.00001)
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: { [weak self] in
            self?.view.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
        })
    }
```

for me this code works

[image: an example of the results of gif using the code above]

Comment: Worked for me!!

Comment: @Ravi nice to hear that